# How to make discord.py bot ignore @everyone mention?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I made a bot for my discord, but I named it after myself. So sometimes the bot accidentally gets mentioned instead of me and I don't receive the notification. I wrote some code that if the bot is ever mentioned it will reply with my id so I get the mention.

**My problem is:** The bot also responds to @everyone, how can I prevent this?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} You probably meant that message for <@my_id>')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a prior if-statement to check if the message mentions everyone, and if so, ignore it.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.mention_everyone:
        return
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} You probably meant that message for <@my_id>')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```